# How to pass xml as Json attribue in postman

Tags: httprequest, postman

I am trying to write a really simple test in Postman. I have two URL and first url get some XML file and then store this in Postman varible as a pre script section.
After that second URL uses this response and send a another request for Post.

but after getting result from xml successfully , somehow postman does not pass this request and gives 400.

```
pm.environment.set('RandomNumber',  "cot"+Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
pm.sendRequest("https://test/metadata.xml", function (err, response) {

    pm.environment.set('**RandomURLText**', response.text());
});
```

RandomURLText varible store the value of first request.

Second request body params looks like below code .

```
**{
    "idPType": "Test",
    "dontShowProgress": true,
    "dontIncludeRequestedAuthnContext": true,
    "nameIDFormat": "run:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient",
    "sigAlg": "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-a",
    "metadata": {
        "idpXml": "{{RandomURLText}}"
    }

}**
```

is there any function postman who can transform this xml response data. Because second request say 400 when it add xml type data. But when I just replaced this responsetext to hello then its works.

That's means something is wrong in xml type data , may be escape chars.

could someone help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

found answer myself, its working. 
Just need to parse into string and need to removed quote from body.

**pm.environment.set('RandomURLText', JSON.stringify(response.text()));**

**{
    "idPType": "Test",
    "dontShowProgress": true,
    "dontIncludeRequestedAuthnContext": true,
    "nameIDFormat": "run:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient",
    "sigAlg": "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-a",
    "metadata": {
        "idpXml": {{RandomURLText}}
    }

}**

Thanks